# Conditional rendering of HTML elements in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am looking to render conditionally some HTML elements of my component.

I have a state variable Boolean, which can be either true (want to render text) or false (want to render nothing).

Inside the return param for the render functon, I have tried the following:

```
{this.state.boolean ? <div><h1>True</h1></div> : <div></div>}

{this.state.boolean && <div><h1>True</h1></div> || <div></div>}
```

But in both cases, the h1 element is rendered regardless of the state of Boolean!

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: nah that should definitely work. Can you post a fiddle of your example or provide more code?

Comment: I can confirm the ternary expression works. Can you please check the type and value of your boolean?

Answer (score 5):

I usually do:

```
outputHTML(boolean) {
   if(!boolean) return null;
   return (
      <div>
        Something you wanted to show if the boolean was present
      </div>
   )
}

render() {
   return (
     <div>
      {this.outputHTML(this.state.boolean)}
     </div>
   )
 }
```

If the HTML you want to conditionally render has alot of conditions or is complex by nature. NOTE: Returning null will just render nothing.

Or the shorter, simpler version:

```
{this.state.boolean && <div><h1>True</h1></div>}
```

If it is not working please provide more context, maybe some error messages or something?

Comment: The shorter, simpler version is great.

Answer (score 2):

This definitely works, which sounds like what you've been doing.

Check the [bin](https://jsbin.com/qomofonera/edit?html,js,output)

https://jsbin.com/qomofonera/edit?html,js,output

```
class Demo extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        boolean: false
    };
  }
  render(){
    return(
        <div>
            {this.state.boolean ? <div><h1>True</h1></div> : <div><h1>False</h1></div>}  
        </div>

    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this doesn't work?

```
class Demo extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        boolean: false
    };
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            {this.state.boolean && <div><h1>True</h1></div>}  
        </div>

    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like the following (h/t to Chad whose code I stole & modified)

```
class Demo extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            boolean: false
        };
    }
    render(){
        var bool = null;
        if (this.state.boolean) {
            bool = (<div><h1>True</h1></div>);
        }
        return(
            <div>
                {bool}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```